# Attributes from one class carrying over to another...

Tags: html, css

Please review the **[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/S77b3/)**...

I am trying to separate some elements here and I'm having a tough time. All my div tags appear correctly separated, but I'm not getting the separation.

For example, I've got a button, then a clear, then a paragraph.

But, the paragraph is actually showing up inside the button, after the clear.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">Transfer of Credit Estimator</div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="classes">Enter total number of classes estimated for transfer, then click <strong>Estimate</strong>.
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="" placeholder="#">
        <div id="btn">Estimate<div> <!-- Button -->
    </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
            <p>Hi</p>

                <div id="footer">**The Estimator is based on classes that would transfer in as 4-credit courses that cost $1,608 each ($402/credit hour) here at University. The Estimator assumes that each class would be a 5-week class.</div> <!-- Footer -->
</div> <!-- Close Container -->
</div>
```

On top of that, the footer is taking on attributes from the '.btn' class, such as the font-family and font-weight.

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button div is not closed. It should be:

```
<div class="btn">Estimate</div>
```

Comment: All my troubles over a little "/"... AMAZING! Thanks for catching it. I've got 10 minutes before I can accept.

Comment: I was just bugged by this in one of my own projects, so I share your frustration :-)

Answer (score 0):

The button div is not closed

```
<div id="btn">Estimate<div>
```

instead it should be

```
<div id="btn">Estimate</div>
```

Your browser tries to correct you missing closing tag and that creates the attributes to shift